# Find the steady state probability that both A and B catch a headache.

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

I have a question about Markov chain. Let A and B be patients, A has headache at the rate $1$ times/week and recovers from it at rate of $2$ times/week. The patient B has it at the rates $2$ and $4$ /week, respectively. How can I find the steady state prob. that both A and B catch a headache? Thanks.

Comment: Are headaches result of A and B hitting each other in the head during a possible fight?

Comment: I think that the question want to find prob. that A and B have headache in same time.

Comment: If you get a headache once a week, what does it mean to recover from it twice a week?

Comment: Using the hint given by A.S. and assuming that upon every fight, either $A$ hits $B$ or $B$ hits $A$, we find the total rate of fights is $3$ per week. So, based on that, can you find the probability that $B$ successfully hits $A$ ?

Comment: @lulu : I'm guessing this problem is worded strangely, where "rate" refers to a transition rate between states, rather than a usual rate (as in $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\mbox{Num headaches up to $t$}}{t}$, which was assumed in my facetious comment above). I think it intends to model 2 independent 2-state Markov continuous time chains.  The $A$ chain has states $Headache (H)$, $None (N)$ and the transition rates are $\lambda_{NH} = 1$, $\lambda_{HN} = 2$.

Comment: @Michael Ah.  Well, I did wonder where Markov chains came into the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $t>0$ let
$$
X(t) = \begin{cases} 
0,& \text{Neither patient has a headache at time } t\\
A,& \text{Patient } A \text{ has a headache at time } t\\
B,& \text{Patient } B \text{ has a headache at time } t\\
AB,& \text{Both patients have a headache at time } t. &
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\{X(t): t\in[0,\infty)\}$ is a continuous-time Markov chain on $S=\{0,A,B,AB\}$ and generator matrix
$$G=\begin{bmatrix}-3 & 1 & 2 & 0\\ 2 & -4 & 0 & 2\\ 4 & 0 & -5 & 1\\ 0 & 2 & 4 &-6 \end{bmatrix}, $$
where $$G_{ij}=\begin{cases} \lambda_{ij},& i\ne j\\ -\sum_{j\ne i} \lambda_{ij},& i=j\end{cases}$$ and $\lambda_{ij}$ are the transition rates.
Let $P(t)$ be the matrix with entries $\mathbb P(X_t = j\mid X_0= i)$. Then $P(t)$ satisfies the forward Kolmogorov equation $$P'(t) = P(t)G, $$
with solution
$$\exp(tG) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(tG)^n}{n!}. $$ 
Since $X$ is irreducible and has a finite state space, it admits a unique stationary distribution. Note that for $s,t>0$
$$P(t+s) = e^{(t+s)G} = e^{tG}e^{sG} = P(t)P(s). $$
So the stationary distribution is given by
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to\infty}\lim_{s\to 0}P(t+s)&= \lim_{t\to\infty}\lim_{s\to 0}P(t)P(s)\\
 &=\lim_{t\to\infty}P(t)\lim_{s\to0}P(0)\\
&= \lim_{t\to\infty}e^{tG}\lim_{s\to0}e^{tS}\\
&=\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{tG}
\end{align}
An extremely tedious computation yields the following for $e^{tG}$:
$$
\scriptsize\begin{pmatrix} \frac{2\, e^{- 3\, t}}{9} + \frac{2\, e^{- 6\, t}}{9} + \frac{e^{- 9\, t}}{9} + \frac{4}{9} & \frac{e^{- 6\, t}}{9} - \frac{2\, e^{- 3\, t}}{9} - \frac{e^{- 9\, t}}{9} + \frac{2}{9} & \frac{e^{- 3\, t}}{9} - \frac{2\, e^{- 6\, t}}{9} - \frac{e^{- 9\, t}}{9} + \frac{2}{9} & \frac{e^{- 9\, t}}{9} - \frac{e^{- 6\, t}}{9} - \frac{e^{- 3\, t}}{9} + \frac{1}{9}\\ \frac{2\, e^{- 6\, t}}{9} - \frac{4\, e^{- 3\, t}}{9} - \frac{2\, e^{- 9\, t}}{9} + \frac{4}{9} & \frac{4\, e^{- 3\, t}}{9} + \frac{e^{- 6\, t}}{9} + \frac{2\, e^{- 9\, t}}{9} + \frac{2}{9} & \frac{2\, e^{- 9\, t}}{9} - \frac{2\, e^{- 6\, t}}{9} - \frac{2\, e^{- 3\, t}}{9} + \frac{2}{9} & \frac{2\, e^{- 3\, t}}{9} - \frac{e^{- 6\, t}}{9} - \frac{2\, e^{- 9\, t}}{9} + \frac{1}{9}\\ \frac{2\, e^{- 3\, t}}{9} - \frac{4\, e^{- 6\, t}}{9} - \frac{2\, e^{- 9\, t}}{9} + \frac{4}{9} & \frac{2\, e^{- 9\, t}}{9} - \frac{2\, e^{- 6\, t}}{9} - \frac{2\, e^{- 3\, t}}{9} + \frac{2}{9} & \frac{e^{- 3\, t}}{9} + \frac{4\, e^{- 6\, t}}{9} + \frac{2\, e^{- 9\, t}}{9} + \frac{2}{9} & \frac{2\, e^{- 6\, t}}{9} - \frac{e^{- 3\, t}}{9} - \frac{2\, e^{- 9\, t}}{9} + \frac{1}{9}\\ \frac{4\, e^{- 9\, t}}{9} - \frac{4\, e^{- 6\, t}}{9} - \frac{4\, e^{- 3\, t}}{9} + \frac{4}{9} & \frac{4\, e^{- 3\, t}}{9} - \frac{2\, e^{- 6\, t}}{9} - \frac{4\, e^{- 9\, t}}{9} + \frac{2}{9} & \frac{4\, e^{- 6\, t}}{9} - \frac{2\, e^{- 3\, t}}{9} - \frac{4\, e^{- 9\, t}}{9} + \frac{2}{9} & \frac{2\, e^{- 3\, t}}{9} + \frac{2\, e^{- 6\, t}}{9} + \frac{4\, e^{- 9\, t}}{9} + \frac{1}{9} \end{pmatrix}
$$
from which it follows that the stationary distribution is
$$\pi = \left(\frac49, \frac29, \frac29,\frac19\right). $$
For a practical way to compute $\pi$, observe that because each row of $G$ sums to $0$, there is a nonzero vector $\nu$ such that $\nu G=0$. Solve this equation and normalize so the entries sum to $1$.

Comment: Very thankful to you. However, could you explain how can we obtain the transition matrix $G$ as above

Comment: That looks painful. Stationary distribution for both $A$ and $B$ is $(2/3,1/3)$, hence probability of both having headache is $1/9$.

Comment: @A.S. I included the explicit form of $e^{tG}$ just to show that it's infeasible to do that by hand. Your idea of decomposing the CTMC is easier for answering this specific question, but less general.

Comment: I mostly commented on combing $C(A)\times C(B)$ into $C(A\times B)$ as it ignores an essential feature of the problem and gains no generality (since you can deal with each chain separately in as much generality as needed).

Comment: @Math1000: If I apply the formula $\pi G=0$, I also find the $\pi$ as your solution. Is it correct if i use $\pi G=0$, $\sum \pi=1$ to find the $\pi$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant at the end of the question, just stated a bit differently. If you have access to something like Matlab, Wolfram Alpha, etc. then you can compute $e^{tG}$ for large $t$ to verify your result - but please don't try to do this by hand.